# How did you install nvm?

Tags: authentication, nvm

I wasn't able to install using the curl command.
Here's the transcript:

$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.2/install.sh | bash

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 13527  100 13527    0     0  13527      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01 48138
=> Downloading nvm from git to '/cygdrive/c/MikesStuff/Pers/Dropbox/Personal/home/.nvm'
=> Cloning into '/cygdrive/c/MikesStuff/Pers/Dropbox/Personal/home/.nvm'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 288, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (288/288), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (258/258), done.
Receiving objects:  87% (251/288)sed 95 (delta 18), pack-reused 0Receiving objects:  8
Receiving objects: 100% (288/288), 146.70 KiB | 2.72 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), done.
error: invalid path 'test/fast/Aliases/"nvm alias" should not accept aliases with slashes'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'

Failed to clone nvm repo. Please report this!

Comment: [Michael Cain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15215073) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278490) saying "If you're using Windows, this link helped me: https://docs.antora.org/antora/2.2/install/windows-requirements/#install-choco
You don't actually need Antora though."